# Pretty URLs Based Off Tag In WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress

need to change the tag path, more seo like. atm my blog archive-page is like "domain.com/blog/", the same template (.php) is used for tags. Then the content that has this tag will be displayed accordingly. The URL here is then "domain.com/blog/?tag=tagname".

How can this be changed so that the path is then as follows: "Domain.com/blog/tag/tagname"?

I found this code in the blog.php.

```
if($_GET['tag']) {
    $tag = trim($_GET['tag']);
    $tag = str_replace(' ', '-', $tag);
}

$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;

if ($tag == "is_page") {
    $the_query = new WP_Query('cat=1,12&paged=' . $paged);
}
else{
    $the_query = new WP_Query('cat=1,12&paged=' . $paged . '&tag=' . $tag);
}
```

Comment: my first idea was, add a function like: `function wpb_change_search_url() {
    if ( is_tag() && ! empty( $_GET['tag'] ) ) {
        wp_redirect( home_url( "/blog/tag/" ) . urlencode( get_query_var( 'tag' ) ) );
        exit();
    }   
}
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'wpb_change_tag_url' );` - But, not working!

Comment: Did you try to add Tag Base from Permalink settings? You don't need to add any code, just go to Settings > Permalink then add `tag` in the Tag base option, and save the settings.

Comment: I did, nothing happend.

Comment: [Sreenshot](https://snipboard.io/kLcBsl.jpg) it should work fine and you should see url like this. You might be doing something wrong. Make sure you remove your custom code and anything else you used to make it work.